# How to define `autocomplete="off"` as a CSS style?

Tags: html, css

To turn off autocompletion in HTML I use:

```html
    <input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

But this forces me to specify `autocomplete="off"` in every input field of my application. Is it possible to define `autocomplete="off"` in a CSS style?

Comment: no, it's not a style - its behaviour.

Comment: It's as simple as @sevenseacat comment. It's a behaviour. You need to write it in the HTML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just apply it to the form tag.

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS you cannot achieve it. You can use client side script for example using Jquery

```
$('input').attr('autocomplete','off');
```

If you are not using Jquery or scripting language then you have to stick to HTML only.

As TeT Psy said you can apply it in form tag like

```
<form id="Form" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I don't use Jquery, sorry

Comment: @ps0604:- Then in that case you have to stick to HTML way. CSS does not provide any such way.

Comment: In my opinion, its not good idea to use JavaScript or jQuery if you can do it in html or css.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:- Yes that is true. I just gave an option. Since OP neglected the idea of using HTML.

Answer (score 2):

you can disable all the autocompletes using `form`

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 2):

U can use **autocomplete="off"** attribute on form tag. Like

```
<form id='test' autocomplete="off">
  <input ...
  <input .. 
   ...
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it on `form` element if you wants to set `autocomplete: off` for all input elements of form. And if wants to make it on for some selected input you can apply `autocomplete: on` on that input.

```css
.form {
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="#" class="form" autocomplete="on">
  <div class="form-group">
    First name:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    Last name:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    E-mail: <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this using css, but there are 2 other ways to do it:

1- you can apply it for the form

```
<form autocomplete="off" >
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="mail">
</form>
```

2- you can handle it using js

```
var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i=0; i<eles.length; i++){
    eles[i].setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ng1mb77m/1/